# if statements based on user input

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to use different if statements based on user input. However it only seems to use the final set. any help would be great thanks.

```
char type[20];
double weight;
double feed;


cout<< "Enter horse type:  ";
cin>>type;
cout << "Enter the horse weight in whole pounds:  "; 
cin>>weight; 
cout<<"Horse type: "<<type<<endl;
cout<<"Horse weight: "<<weight<<endl;
```

This is my if statements.

```
  {
    if (type=="Light");
    if (weight >= 840 && weight <=1200) 
    feed = (3.0); 
    else if (weight< 840)
    feed = (3.3);
    else if (weight > 1200)
    feed = (2.5);
    }
    {
    if (type=="Large");
     if (weight >= 1100 && weight <=1300) 
    feed=(3.0);
    else if (weight < 1100)
    feed=(3.3);
    else if (weight > 1300)
    feed= (2.5);
    }
    {

    if (type=="Draft");
    if (weight >= 1500&& weight <=2200) 
    feed = (3.0); 
    else if (weight< 1500)
    feed = (3.3);
    else if (weight >2200)
    feed= (2.5); 
    }

    cout<<"Feed Amount "<<feed<<" pounds"<<endl;
```

Thanks again for any help

Comment: Your coude would be much easier to read with proper indentation

Comment: It is also traditional to use else if after the first if for mutually exclusives if blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare C-style strings (character arrays) using `==`. That compares the addresses of the arrays, not their contents.

Use `std::string` instead. Replace the first line with

```
std::string type;
```

You also need to fix the `if` statements:

```
if (type == "Whatever")  // no ;
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I got it to work with a combination of both yours and Matt's answers. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
{
if (type=="Light");
```

should be:

```
if ( type == "Light" )
{
```

and the same for Draft and Large.  What you are actually doing is taking no action regardless of the `if`, and always executing the following code.

Also ( as noted by Mike Seymour ) change `char type[20];` to `std::string type;`.  If you really must stick to `char`, then you will also need to change your comparison.

If your compiler supports C++14 then:

```
if ( type == "Light"s )
```

Otherwise:

```
if ( type == std::string("Light") )
```

For any of these cases you need `#include <string>` at the top of your file.